# bundle and minification return 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, bundling-and-minification

1. Package `System.Web.Optimization`has Been Installed
2. bundle has been configured as below

   ```
   using System.Web.Optimization;
   public class BundleConfig
   {
       public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
       {
           bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/themes/base/js").Include("~/Scripts/Site.js"));
           bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include("~/Content/Site.css"));

       }
   }
   ```
3. add this to Layout.cshtml

   ```
   @System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/Content/themes/base/js")
   @System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
   ```

css minified succesfully but return 404 error for js file ?

Comment: Well you *do* have `Site.js` in `Scripts`, right ?

Comment: yes i can access through web browser to that . `htt://localhost:8777/Scripts/Site.js`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that your virtual path for your bundle `Content/themes/base/js` does not relate to a real path.  Generally we use `~/bundles` in our virtual path for this reason.

**Example**

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/base/js").Include("~/Scripts/Site.js"));
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/base/css").Include("~/Content/Site.css"));

}
```

Comment: yes ,your right . it should not be same as exist physical location.

Answer (score 6):

I suddenly received 404 errors on one of my production servers for my sites script bundle resource.

After a bit of searching I found [this blogpost](http://blog.cdeutsch.com/2012/11/fixing-404-errors-for-aspnet-mvc-apps.html) that suggest the following solution that should be used in `web.config` in the section `system.webServer` that worked great.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="BundleModule" />
    <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
</modules>
```

Comment: This is what fixed it for me